# Update internal state based on props (anti-pattern)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am fairly new to react and redux but I've worked with Angular/Vue for a bit.

I have a component that has internal state to track setting an `is-active` class on a modal. There is a form on this modal that will make an AJAX request using the `redux-thunk` middleware. I need to know when/if this AJAX requests succeeds, and if so, close the modal (remove the `is-active` class).

I was considering making the component a [fully controlled](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-controlled-component) component but that would mean putting this in the redux store to set state on successful AJAX requests.

I also see `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated and an anti-pattern apparently and I really don't want to use anti-patterns in my application. Is there any other way to do this scenario? *Any* help is appreciated!!

Comment: I don't see any other way but relying on the value in the store... How else can you access a value that is set by an action?

Comment: @Rahamin you're right, I ended up just create a reducer for my modal with open/close methods to dispatch when needed. I like this solution better than essentially implementing a callback.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the new static method `getDerivedStateFromProps`, you could do something like this (make sure you are using `react: ^16.3.0`):

```
state = { is_active: false, _is_active: false }

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, current_state) {
  // you can should set isOpen via a props
  // so based on your ajax call you can set this to false
  let { isOpen } = nextProps;
  if (isOpen !== current_state._is_active) {
    return {
      _is_active: isOpen,
      is_active: isOpen
    }
  }
  return { _is_active: false }
}
```

Then you can set your modal to close internally via `this.state.is_active` or to show and close externally via the `isOpen` prop